# Maven mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml problems

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I've been going through most of the various problems people have with the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml files and I've encountered most of the problems myself.
The errors are never specific to one of the xml namespaces as I've had almost all of them give the various problems. 
Problems Include:

- Referenced file contains errors
- Errors on the source page
- The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element

I've tried the various solutions to the problem as well including:

- Referencing a specific .xsd file and not just the one without a version
- Ensuring that my spring versions in my pom file match the versions specified in my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

I know theres many of these posts on stackoverflow but I still couldn't find a solution to mine through them.

The code that I used is as follows:

**POM File**

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
....
```

**mvc-disptacher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.epiuse.AdapterTool.controller"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="resources/"></mvc:resources>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your problem is????

Comment: @M.Deinum that my xml file keeps having those problems that I stated.

Comment: And you get those errors when? In eclipse, ignore them, at startup you have the wrong spring version in your classpath. General advice use the version less schemas as that is the recommended approach...

Comment: @M.Deinum ahh well that makes more sense, I spent ages trying to clear the errors. Why does eclipse produce these errors though ? But I was using the version less schemas at first but just kept trying different approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: I might be biased on this but XML validation with (plain) eclipse is painful especially when the XSD files are shipped in a jar (like spring) and loaded with a custom resolver (like spring). Also when using STS it might take a newer version for being able to use the newest XSD version (although it should parse the `spring.schemas` files).

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah, previously I used IntelliJ for this type of work and didn't have any of the these problems. I turned off validation now and stuck to using the version less XSD files. Thanks for the help, those errors were driving me mad.

Comment: Then why did you switch :)... (Switched to Intellij years ago never looked back).

Comment: @M.Deinum Theres a plugin I need for what I'm working on and its only provided for eclipse :(, no support for IntelliJ just yet

Comment: Then just use the plugin and do everthing else in Intellij? What specific thing you need?

Comment: @M.Deinum its a SAP HANA integration plugin, just decided to go with eclipse as theirs a lot more information available for it.